# as3 real fireworks

Tags: actionscript-3, fireworks

Is there any actionscript 3 class for fireworks that looks like real and not just some kind of bubbles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to look into particles, there are plenty of libraries out there.

Have a look at this one for instance
http://desuade.com/partigen

Comment: yeah. It seems particles library is a best shot. Used "flint" particles library.